# Why do they use 'to' preposition in 'rose to popularity' here?

Tags: word-usage

Why do they use 'to' preposition in 'rose to popularity' here?

> The Wallace E. Pratt house, also known as the Ship on the Desert, sits
>   within the Guadalupe Mountains National Park in Texas. The house was
>   the home of scientist Wallace Pratt. It was built in the modern
>   “International Style” of architecture that **rose to popularity**
>   beginning in the 1920s.

Comment: And we can **sink (or fall) into obscurity**.   "popularity" and "obscurity" are *states*, not vehicles or instrumentalities.  The verbs mean "become" with a directional flavor. became popular, became obscure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rising to** here is like moving **from** a *lower/lying* position (from being ignored by the architects) **to** a *higher/standing* position (**to popularity**). A similar expression is often used: *rise to power*.

Answer (score 1):

If X is a destination, and something is moving toward it, you can say *to X*.  Common especially with verbs of motion like *rise.*

Comment: so popularity is a destination here? Could you give other variant of meaning of 'rose to popularity'? Can we say something 'rise using popularity' or 'rise on popularity' are they the same meaning?

Comment: You can say something rises *to* popularity in the same way.

Comment: Now I got it. I thought it used to be popular to built such architectural style. What is probably the same 'to be popular' or  'rise to popularity'.